# I try to simulate some embedded protocol, I can't find which check sum algorithm it use. Is there any other algorithm?

Tags: embedded

```
Length|Data0|Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4|Data5|Data6|Data7|Checksum|
9     |3    |41   |0    |70   |77   |55   |32   |0    |205     |
9     |3    |41   |0    |70   |77   |54   |32   |0    |206     |
```

I only familiar with BRC,CRC,LRC, No one works, is there any other common algorithm in embbeded?

Additional info:

```
Length  Data0   Data1   Data2   Data3   Data4   Data5   Data6   Data7   Data8   Data9   Data10  Data11  Data12  Data13  Data14  Data15  Data16  CheckSum
18      3       38      1       0       1       11      16      57      48      46      51      32      77      72      122     0       0       56
18      3       38      1       0       1       11      16      57      50      46      50      32      77      72      122     0       0       55
```

Comment: Does the protocol documentation/specification not say anything about the checksum algorithm?

Comment: No, I do not have protocol specification. The original device send ASCII chars to the screen, I try to simulate the original device protocol to show my own chars on the screen.

Comment: If you sum all the data and checksum bytes and then mask the result to one byte it equals 0xE3.  Maybe that's all there is to it.  Do you have anymore examples?

Comment: @kkrambo yes, please see addtional info.

Comment: Please show also shorter messages with one two or three bytes length. It seems to be a negative sum with some sort of offset

Comment: @jeb Unfortunately, I can't find any more shorter message.

Comment: Then you should add more messages with some data modifications, as with these 4 it's hard to guess how the checksum works. Currently it's `-(sumOfMessage + 20) % 256` for the 9bytes messages and `-(sumOfMessage + 179) % 256` for the 18bytes messages

Comment: Maybe if you told us what the device was someone may have experience or knowledge of it.